# Super resolution for narrowband signal

Tags: frequency, bandwidth, multipath, superresolution

How effective it is to apply super resolution techniques (like MUSIC, ESPRIT) on low bandwidth signals for indoor (BW=30Mhz) and outdoor (BW = 1MHz) location estimation?

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  Can you please give us more information? What do you mean by "super resolution techniques" ? Do you have any specific ones in mind? What is your goal for the narrowband signal? What you are trying to achieve will change what we suggest you try. Please [edit your question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/76877/edit) and add these details to the question.